# Plotting Acoustic Waveform - Magnitude on a Linear Frequency Scale

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition

I have an acoustic waveform of a Spanish phoneme and I'd like to compute its magnitude spectrum and plot it in dB magnitude on a linear frequency scale. How would I be able to accomplish this in MATLAB?

Thanks

Comment: For _spectrum_: `fft`, then `abs`, and don't forget `fftshift` for the plot. For _spectrogram_: `spectrogram`, which already gives power density, so no need for `abs`

Answer (score 1):

First a quick heads up: At stackoverflow you are expected to show some of your own efforts to solve the problem and then ask for help.

Now to your question:

You can plot the spectrogram using the "spectrogram" Matlab function.

```
[s,f,t] = spectrogram(x,window,noverlap,f,fs)
```

Check the details here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html

For a speech signal you will want to specify the sampling frequency "fs" (you can get that when you read the file using:

```
[y,Fs] = audioread(filename)
```

You will probably want to specify the variables "window" and "noverlap" since speech signals can show distinct properties depending on the dimension of the window (fast phenomena will not be visible on big windows ). A typical values are 20ms windows with 10ms overlap (select the best value by considering your sampling frequency and the nearest 2^n value for fast Fourier calculation).

The window size and overlap are also valid when you calculate spectrum. If you apply FFT to the whole waveform then you will get the "average" spectral information for the sentence. To catch specific phenomena you must use windowing techniques and perform a short-term Fourier analysis.

Answer (score 0):

use `sptool`

Signal Processing toolbox [Show its Document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sptool.html)